# Why is using MappingCharFilter in Lucene 4,1 analyzer breaking wildcard matches

Tags: java, lucene

Using MappingCharFilter in analyzer breaking wildcard matches

I created this simple StripSpacesAndSeparatorsAnalyzer

```
public class StripSpacesAndSeparatorsAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

    protected NormalizeCharMap charConvertMap;

    protected void setCharConvertMap() {

        NormalizeCharMap.Builder builder = new NormalizeCharMap.Builder();
        builder.add(" ","");
        builder.add("-","");
        builder.add("_","");
        builder.add(":","");
        charConvertMap = builder.build();
    }

    public StripSpacesAndSeparatorsAnalyzer() {
        setCharConvertMap();
    }

    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, 
                                                     Reader reader) {
        Tokenizer source = new KeywordTokenizer(reader);
        TokenStream filter = new LowercaseFilter(source);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
    }


    @Override
    protected Reader initReader(String fieldName,
                                Reader reader)
    {
        return new MappingCharFilter(charConvertMap, reader);
    }
}
```

so that it ignores certain characters such as hyphens in the field so that I can search for

```
catno:WRATHCD25
catno:WRATHCD-25
```

and get the same results, and that works (the original value of the field added to the index was WRATHCD-25)

However there is a problem with wildcard searching

```
catno:WRATHCD25*
```

works, but

```
catno:WRATHCD-25*
```

does not

If I amend the analyzer to comment out the initReader() method then

```
catno:WRATHCD-25*
```

now works but of course

```
catno:WRATHCD25
```

no longer works.

Wham I doing wrong please

Comment: Are you passing the same Analyzer in to the [`QueryParser` ctor](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParser.html#QueryParser(org.apache.lucene.util.Version,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer))?

Comment: Yes i am passing the same analyer

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess: to parse the query, you are using regular `QueryParser`, right?

Try using [`AnalyzingQueryParser`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/analyzing/AnalyzingQueryParser.html), it should do the trick. From the javadoc:

> Overrides Lucene's default QueryParser so that Fuzzy-, Prefix-,
>   Range-, and WildcardQuerys are also passed through the given analyzer,
>   but wild card characters (like *) don't get removed from the search
>   terms.

Comment: Yes I am, alright I will try that, but I dont understand why the regular query parser only brreaks when using my analyzer.

Comment: @PaulTaylor to see why your analyzer doesn't work, try debugging it when it tokenizez stuff (both queries and indexed fields) and see what tokens it actually makes. Then try adding/removing/modifying stuff in it so that it creates the tokens you want